# Find area of trapezoid contained in circle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> The picture below represents a circumference of radius 5 and center at
>   the origin of the referencial 0xy. In the picture is represented too a
>   trapezoid [ABCD], with [AD] and [BC] parallel. A is the point of the
>   circumference that belongs to the x axis. Points B and C belong to the
>   circumference. D belongs to the 0x axis and has x-coordinate
>   $-\frac{5}{2}$. Consider $AÔB = \alpha, \alpha \in ]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$.
>
> [image]
>
> Show that the area of the trapezoid in function of $\alpha$ is given
>   by:
>
> $$A(\alpha) = 25\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)+\frac{75}{4}\sin(\alpha)$$

First I tried to calculate the area of the whole trapezoid at once and so I got:

$$\frac{2 \cdot 5\cos(\alpha)+(5+\frac{5}{2})}{2}\cdot 5\sin(\alpha)$$

But when I put this one and the given one in the calculator they gave different values, so I tried dividing the main trapezoid in two smaller ones at the y axis and I got:

\begin{align} 25\sin(\alpha) \cdot \frac{\cos(\alpha)+1}{2}+25\sin(\alpha) \cdot \frac{2\cos(\alpha)+1}{4 }= \\
25\sin(\alpha)\Bigg(\frac{\cos(\alpha)+1}{2}+\cdot \frac{2\cos(\alpha)+1}{4}\Bigg) = \\
25\sin(\alpha)\Bigg(\frac{4(\cos(\alpha)+1)+2(2\cos(\alpha)+1)}{8}\Bigg) = \\
25\sin(\alpha)\Bigg(\frac{\cos(\alpha)+1+4\cos(\alpha)+2}{4}\Bigg) = \\
25\sin(\alpha)\Bigg(\frac{5\cos(\alpha)+3}{4}\Bigg) = ??? \end{align}

I have two questions:

1. Why didn't my first attempt work?
2. How do I solve this, continuing with my second one?

Comment: The equation you have to prove and your first work concur. Using the height as $5sin\alpha$ and $BC=10cos\alpha$ and using the standard formula for trapezoid, I arrived at the to be proven equation. Not sure about the "when I put it in the calculator..." part. Sure that you put it all correct? Brackets etc....

Comment: @imranfat When I say "I put it in the calculator" I mean I put the given on as Y1 and mine as Y2 and compared the results. It they are the same, I know I am doing it correctly. This way I save time. If the first one works for you, then I might have written it wrong in the calculator.

Comment: I derived the area formula myself and then compared with yours. Played around with it and calculated that for $\alpha=57$ the area is at it largest. Not part of your problem, but interesting nonetheless. As far as your second part is concerned, don't know where you went wrong, but I think that approach is unnecessarily difficult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct but you did not continue with the first formula you derived: $$ {2⋅5cos\alpha+(5+5/2)\over 2}⋅5sin\alpha = 5{10\over 2}cos\alpha sin\alpha + 5{7.5\over 2}sin\alpha ⇒ \\ A(\alpha) = 25sin\alpha cos\alpha +{75\over 4}sin\alpha$$

Here's an alternative way:
We have to notice that as the angle a changes the point B changes and in order for the trapezoid to remain a trapezoid that means point C changes in order to stay paraller with AD. So: $$ A\hat OB = C\hat OD $$
Because BD and AD are parallel that means: $$ O\hat BC = O\hat CB $$
If we calculate the area of OAB triangle in terms of the angle α we got: $$ OA = 5\\ sin\alpha = h/5 \Rightarrow h = 5sin\alpha \\ AreaOfOAB = {25\over 2}sin\alpha$$
If we calculate the area of OCD triangle in terms of the angle α we got: $$ OD = 2.5\\ sin\alpha = h/5 \Rightarrow h = 5sin\alpha \\ AreaOfOCD = {12.5\over 2}sin\alpha$$
Now let's look at the OCB triangle: $$ cos\alpha = {(BC/2)\over 5}={BC\over 10} \Rightarrow BC = 10cos\alpha \\sinα=h/5⇒h=5sinα\\ AreaOfOCB = 25sin\alpha cos\alpha$$
Now if we add them we got: $$ A(\alpha) = 25sin\alpha cos\alpha +{75\over 4}sin\alpha$$[image]